# What case should a name use after the preposition 'with'?

Tags: падежи, существительные, предлоги

See for example the following sentence:

> В Париж с Константином Коровиным

Why the -ом on the first name and -ым on the last name?  Are there any other words besides "with" that would see this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the `-ом` on the first name and `-ым` on the last name?

The last names with this paradigm (ending in `-ов`, `-ев`, `-ёв`, `-ин`, `-ын` and their female counterparts) developed from posessive adjectives and decline like those, though keeping the old short form paradigm: *Коровина*, *Коровину* rather than ***Коровиного*, ***Коровиному*.

Actually, *Коровин* is a contraction of *Коровин сын*: a son of a person named, dubbed, nicknamed, or otherwise yclept *корова* (cow).

Until quite recently, it was the way to write the patronymics (*Иван Петров сын Сидоров*), and it's still used in Bulgarian.

Note that this paradigm is only valid for last names of this origin.

Names originated from other languages (*Асприн*, *Толкин* etc.) are declined as nouns (*Асприном*, *Толкином*).

Russian names which have not originated from posessive adjectives (*Литвин*, *Мордвин*) also decline as nouns (*Литвином*, *Мордвином*). However, the names' origins in this case are not obvious from sg. nom., so these last names can decline as posessive adjectives as well, and only the name bearer may know the right form.

The name of Ivan Ivanovich Sakharine, the antagonist in "Tintin's adventures", is declined *Сахариным*, not *Сахарином* in Russian translation (though both versions are grammatically possible). It's believed it should be an old aristocratic family name originated from the word *сахар* (sugar), not quite a recent nick originated from *сахарин* (saccharin).

Comment: Nowadays it seems to be the paradigm of short forms of qualitative adjectives like "красен-красна-красно".

Comment: I've just realized that I cannot come up with any short adjective in non-nominative case. It must really be the old form, but now it is only present in all forms in surnames (who would actually say о мамине супе?)

Comment: @Olga: for the posessive adjectives, the modern language uses short form for sg. nom. and full form for oblique cases. The proper full form for sg. nom. would be ***маминый*. This is also the case for third-person pronouns which use the remote form (*он*, *она*, *они*) in nom. and proximal form (*его*, *её*, *их*) for oblique cases. The proximal third-person pronouns is what the full adjective form developed from.

Answer (score 4):

Nice question! The difference is that *Константин* is a first name, while *Коровин* is a surname. According to [the rules](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/28.htm), surnames ending with the suffixes *-ин* / *-ын* get the ending *-ым* in the instrumental case. Константин, on the contrary, has the usual ablative index *-ом*.

Interestingly, if a surname becomes a city name, the above rule is not applicable any more: *Голицын — За Голицином*.

Comment: The city name is Голицынo, not Голицын. The gender is not the same, hence the different form.

Comment: @A-K: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BD_(%D0%91%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that -ин surnames have the same declension as adjectives. That's why it is "Сталиным", "Путиным" rather than "Сталином", "Путином".

Comment: Not exactly the same, or at least not the same as "normal" adjectives like "красный".

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the first name here is of noun-type, that conjugate as noun, and surname is possessive adjective (roughly translated like cow's), that became surname, and conjugates as possesive adjective. So, they have different conjugated forms. Moreover, this surname conjugates with male and female first names differently.

Not, however, a special case of adjectives, ended with "-ин", that have two variants of conjugation in some cases, ending with "-а" or "-ого", that may be confusing. The first variant is standard for surnames, but the second is dominating in other cases.

Comment: Sorry, but surnames are not declined as possessive adjectives. "Нет маминого супа", but "нет Коровина".

Comment: @Olga: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm: *возможны варианты окончаний в родительном и дательном падежах мужского и среднего рода прилагательных на -ин; ср.: возле дедушкина дома – возле дедушкиного дома;*.

Comment: Then maybe the answer should say so =)

Comment: @Olga yes, they are. However, you correctly noted the special case.

Comment: @permeakra Can you please decline Коровин and мамин суп to see for yourself that the forms coincide only in Nominative and Instrumental case and not in other cases? In Genitive, Dative and Prepositional cases the forms are different: говорили о мамином супе - о Коровине.

Comment: @Olga, Please, check yourself with female obj, i.e. `мамина дочь/Коровина Констанция` and then again with `Отцов cын/Коровин Константин`. BTW, please, do not check against word with different animacy (Who/What), as they conjugates slightly different.

Comment: I still think that paradigms are different, because they are different for at least one gender of word that end on -ин. Also, I've just noticed that you had edited your answer and had mentioned two different paradigms. I think that this is an important detail, and it has been included, and I will not bug you anymore.

Comment: @Olga, please. Most Russian surnames are derived from either possessive adjectives, or simple adjectives. The idea was that they had to answer which family this given Ivan belongs to, i.e. `Иван, Иванов (внук)`, or which land he came from, i.e. `Оксана Рязанская`. This is why `Кузнецов (сын)`, not `Кузнец` (Smith). Later, different historic events slightly changed things, some surnames was imported from foreign states, some neologisms was created, and language evolved, but the base still remains clearly visible. This *-ин issue is special, not the surnames in general. And yes, it is special.

Comment: @permeakra I agree with what you say about the history of words. But I am talking about paradigms, which are parts of the current state of the language.